# sum of two lists with lists in R

Tags: r, list, sum

Is there an easy way to do a simple calculation in a list of lists?

```
x <- list(a=list(1:4),b=list(1:6))
y <- list(a=list(1:4),b=list(1:6))
```

When I try:

```
x+y
```

I receive the error:
Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator

X and y are equal lengths, and contain only integers. With a matrix it is possible to do y+x, is there a way to do this for lists with lists?

Comment: Simply using "+" is not implemented for `list`. This is because a `list` can contain any R object. Therefore, there is no non-ambiguous way of adding up the elements of a `list`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to go through each 2 lists simultaneously.

```
 lapply(seq_along(x),function(i)
         unlist(x[i])+unlist(y[i]))

[[1]]
a1 a2 a3 a4 
 2  4  6  8 

[[2]]
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 
 2  4  6  8 10 12
```

if x and y don't have the same length, you can do this :

```
 lapply(seq_len(min(length(x),length(y)),function(i)
         unlist(x[i])+unlist(y[i]))
```

Comment: Another nice answer!, didn't know this use of lapply, I always used lapply over an list so the element was used in the function, but using that way I couldn't get that y element.

Comment: @Jetse lapply can be iterated through any list or iterator. But here the solution is `mapply`

Comment: Selected this answer because this keeps my list structure.

Comment: @Jetse, `lapply` and `mapply` are giving you the same structure.  What you are seeing different is the names the elements are receiving.

Answer (score 10):

assuming each list has the same structure, you can use `mapply` as follows

```
  mapply(function(x1, y1) x1[[1]]+y1[[1]], x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, mapply was the function I was looking for! Didn't know this function before, only knew apply and lapply...

Comment: Used it on my final dataset, then I discovered I losed my list structure, agstudy his answer keeps my list structure.

Comment: @Jetse try adding `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`.

Comment: With simplify=FALSE I only keep the first list, and still lose these lists in this list.